# Where to search for a file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, search

In past versions of Windows I'd go to *Start* → *Search*, put the name of the file and search the entire file tree.

In Windows 10 home version 2004 build 19041.746, when I go to *Start* I can only search for "windows" of system options but not for files; if I run a search on a file's name I am being referred to search it in the web via Bing web browser as if it was web data.

I went to "Windows search settings" and found data about indexing files in my PC but I don't want to index anything; I don't care how much time searching the file tree takes --- I just want to search a particular file in all non excluded folders (under "Find my files" I have changed from *classic* to *enhanced*), **but where to search for a file in Windows 10?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a file via the search bar in the upper right of any window. The default behavior is to search from that folder and deeper.

To search your entire computer type `Win` + `E` to open the "This PC", the search bar will say "Search This PC".

If you want to search a specific drive, open that drive and the search will say "Search [Drive Name] ([Drive Letter]:)" (or whatever drive you open).

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to do a file search from "File Explorer".

1. I have opened File Explorer directly or by opening some directory
2. I clicked to the partition I'd like to search in (gladly I have only one partition) --- `Local Disk (C:)`
3. I went to the small search box at the top right part of the File Explorer Window
4. I have done the search on the entire file tree

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0hwp.jpg)
<sub>This is where I made the search and the output I got.</sub>

### Classic style search

The classic style search of going to *Start* → *Search* no longer exists in Windows 10 but I understand from John in the comments that the closest thing existing in Windows 10 is hitting *Start*, typing the file name, and then, on the top of the window, from the left, switching a tab from the "All" tab to "Documents" tab; I would opine that I find this tab menu inaccessible and confusing both by graphics and by terminology "documents" instead just "files".
Moreover the "classic style" I meant to here doesn't have anything to do with the "classic/enhanced" distinction I have described in the question.